# What should I subclass UICollectionViewLayout or UICollectionViewFlowLayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I have the sketch of the layout as follows :-

[image: Layout Sketch for iPhone]

Above Image, has fixed layout structure as follows

-> First Row has item no.1 and takes all the width of the collection view.

->Second row has item no. 2 and 3 and shares the width equally.

->third row onwards we have to use the default size.

here item1, item2-item3 and all rest of the items have 3 different designs respectively.

the collectionview has 1 section and the datasource over here simple nsarray.

So my question over here is what should I be using ? Any suggestions will be helpful, I am new to UICollectionView and I am finding it little difficult to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can just use UICollectionViewFlowLayout with a collection view which has two different Cell Kinds. No subclass necessary. This may get hairy if you expect your layout to change when in landscape mode.

The first cell kind would be for items 1, 2, and 3. You'll go your different layout by implementing the `collectionView:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:` method. Just make sure index 0(item 1) is full width, and index 1, 2(item 2,3) are half width.

Then you can implement another cell kind for everything else. These items will be full width as well.

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you'll need to check the indexPath's item property to see which index you are. If > 2, use the second cell kind.

Comment: I have different layouts for iPhone and iPad that's why i have to sub class it.

Comment: Depending on your iPad layout you could just create two device specific classes that implement the collectionView and collectionViewLayout delegate methods. If you're iPad layout doesn't fit into a flow layout then yes, subclassing is necessary.